# pass data between screens with getParamas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm rendering a few items in my map in `ContactList`and upon clicking on the thumbnail, I want to navigate to a new screen `UserDetailsScreen` such that the data about the clicked item is also passed along.

Previously I was using modals, but now I trying to switch to react-navigation.

ContactList.tsx:

```
export const ContactList: React.FunctionComponent<UserProps> = ({
  data,
  onDeleteContact,
}) => {
  const [isUserVisible, setIsUserVisible] = useState(false);
  //const [visibleUser, setVisibleUser] = useState<any>();
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <View style={styles.users}>
      {data.users.nodes[0].userRelations.map(
        (item: { relatedUser: RelatedUser; id: number }) => {
          const numberOfFriends = item.relatedUser.userRelations.length;
          const numberPlate = 'WHV AB 123';
          return (
            <View style={styles.item} key={item.id}>
              {/* <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setIsUserVisible(true)}> */}
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() =>
                  navigation.navigate('UserDetailsScreen', {
                    firstName: item.relatedUser.firstName,
                    rating: item.relatedUser.rating,
                    numberOfFriends: numberOfFriends,
                    onDeleteContact: onDeleteContact,
                    isUserVisible: isUserVisible,
                    setIsUserVisible: setIsUserVisible,
                    numberPlate: numberPlate,
                    navigation: navigation,
                  })
                }>
                <Thumbnail
                  }}></Thumbnail>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <View style={styles.nameNumber}>
                <Text style={styles.userName}>{userName}</Text>
              </View>
              {/* <UserDetails
                firstName={item.relatedUser.firstName}
                rating={item.relatedUser.rating}
                numberOfFriends={numberOfFriends}
                onDeleteContact={onDeleteContact}
                isUserVisible={isUserVisible}
                setIsUserVisible={setIsUserVisible}
                  numberPlate={numberPlate}>
                </UserDetails> */}
            </View>
          );
        },
      )}
    </View>
  );
};
```

UserDetailsScreen:

```
export const UserDetailsScreen: React.FunctionComponent<UserProps> = ({
  firstName,
  rating,
  numberOfFriends,
  numberPlate,
  onDeleteContact,
  navigation,
//   isUserVisible,
//   setIsUserVisible,
}) => {
//const navigation = useNavigation();
const fName = navigation.getParam('firstName')
  return (
    // <Modal visible={isUserVisible}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.cross}
            //onPress={() => setIsUserVisible(false)}>
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Whitelist')}>
            <Thumbnail></Thumbnail>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.searchLocationContainer}>
          <UserInfoContainer
            firstName={firstName}
            rating={rating}
            numberPlate={numberPlate}
            numberOfFriends={numberOfFriends}></UserInfoContainer>
        </View>
      </View>
    // </Modal>
  );
};
```

Similarly, when I click on the thumbnail on this screen, I want to go back to my previous page where I can click on another object.

However, I keep getting an error that `navigation.getParam` is undefined. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you will get the data sent in the navigation params in 
`props.route.params`

Comment: Could you please copy and make changes in my code? I don't really get how/where to use ```props.route.params```. Note that I am using typescript

Comment: You just need to use this ``` let fName = props.route.params``` to the screen where you are navigation.
in your case the screen is ```UserDetailsScreen```